# Vim :tnext doesn't move cursor to the next tag

Tags: vim, ctags

I tried to use ctags with vim and I discovered the following problem:

First, let's see the following picture: [image]
If I press C-] then the cursor will move on line 7 as you can see here: [image]

But if I type the command :tn the cursor is still on line 7 instead of line 14, where the next tag is. Why is this happening and how can I solve this? If you look at the following picture [image] on the bottom left it shows: "tag 2 of 3" so that means :tn works, I think, but the cursor doesn't move.

Comment: Read `:help :tnext` again.

Comment: @romainl, it says: jump to [count] next matching tag, where [count] is 1 by default. I read the tag-! section too, and I saw that if the tag is in current file the following action will be performed: goto tag. And this is exactly what I am expecting, but unfortunately it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: You can show the list by `:tselect` to understand `tag 2 of 3`.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス I saw what `tag 2 of 3` means with `:tselect` and it points correctly to the 2nd tag, but I still don't understand why the cursor doesn't go to the 2nd tag, that's my problem. It may be because of the fact that all functions are exactly the same? But they are from different classes so it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your `tags` file you can see that your three definitions for `fc()` are identical:

```
fc  pam.cpp /^        void fc() {$/;"   f   class:A
fc  pam.cpp /^        void fc() {$/;"   f   class:B
fc  pam.cpp /^        void fc() {$/;"   f   class:C
```

By default, Ctags doesn't provide a line:column information to Vim, it merely provides a search pattern. Since it's the same search pattern for all three tags, Vim always performs the same search and always ends up at the same spot. It doesn't matter if you use `:tag fc`, `<C-]>`, `:tnext`, `:tselect` or any of their friends.

With the `-n` option, Ctags outputs line numbers instead of search patterns:

```
fc  pam.cpp 14;"    f   class:B
fc  pam.cpp 21;"    f   class:C
fc  pam.cpp 7;" f   class:A
```

That's better because Vim can now jump to the correct line but the tags are ordered incorrectly. One way to fix this would be to use the `-u` option:

```
A   pam.cpp 5;" c   file:
fc  pam.cpp 7;" f   class:A
B   pam.cpp 12;"    c   file:
fc  pam.cpp 14;"    f   class:B
C   pam.cpp 19;"    c   file:
fc  pam.cpp 21;"    f   class:C
```

In conclusion, you should generate your `tags` with the `-n` and `-u` options. Something like:

```
$ ctags -Rnu .
```

See `$ man ctags`.

Comment: I thought that Vim will see that they are from different classes, but then I read `:help ctags` and I saw that `;"` is interpreted by Vi as the start of a comment (I didn't know that) so the following will be ignored and Vim will not see that they are from different classes. It all makes sense now. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Vim simply doesn't care about the class or anything except the filename and the ex command to perform.

Comment: I saw your edit, and that's exactly how I wanted ctags to work, thanks again, you helped me alot.